# H2 DB identity() function not working in embedded mode

Tags: h2

I am using the H2 database. I have a table with an identity column. I perform an insert and then try and call the identity() function to determine the id assigned to the newly created row.

here is the code snippet I use to call the identity function:

```
CallableStatement cs = dbConnection.prepareCall("{ ? = call IDENTITY()}");
cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.BIGINT);
cs.execute();
id = cs.getLong(1);
cs.close();
```

The problem I run into is that for some reason this function works in server mode, but gives me this error when I call the function in embedded mode:

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Parameter "#1" is not set; SQL statement:
  ? = call IDENTITY() [90012-160]

Comment: I can't reproduce the exception when using your code.